# Bluetooth: Pairing two ubuntu 13.10 machines for audio streaming fails

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, a2dp

I'm trying to stream audio over bluetooth from my laptop to my nas. Both run ubuntu 13.10.

I have so far successfully streamed music form three different android phones to the nas.

The nas pair's with android devices without any configuration, I have however changed the device class to `0x200414` (obtained from http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/software/bluetooth_class_of_device-service_generator.html) which is an Audio device class.

When trying to pair the two ubuntu machines using the gui I get the message:

'Konfiguration von "nas" ist gescheitert' ('Configuration of 'nas' failed').

Below is the logfile of the nas (`00:1E:10:00:14:F6`):

```
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Starting SDP server
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Failed to init time plugin
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Failed to init alert plugin
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: input-headset driver probe failed for device BC:F5:AC:60:BA:A4
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: input-headset driver probe failed for device 08:37:3D:06:8F:10
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Adapter /org/bluez/6902/hci0 has been enabled
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.246 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.246 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.246 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Feb  8 18:43:32 nas bluetoothd[6902]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.246 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Feb  8 18:44:18 nas bluetoothd[6902]: No agent available for request type 0
Feb  8 18:44:18 nas bluetoothd[6902]: btd_event_request_pin: Operation not permitted
```

and the laptop (`D0:DF:9A:B5:81:D5`):

```
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Starting SDP server
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: DIS cannot start: GATT is disabled
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Failed to init deviceinfo plugin
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Failed to init proximity plugin
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Failed to init time plugin
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Failed to init alert plugin
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Failed to init thermometer plugin
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Failed to init gatt_example plugin
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Bluetooth Management interface initialized
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: input-headset driver probe failed for device 08:37:3D:06:8F:10
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Adapter /org/bluez/10747/hci0 has been enabled
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Unknown command complete for opcode 19
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPAG
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/HFPHS
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Feb  8 18:43:36 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.58 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Feb  8 18:43:52 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Discovery session 0x7f79ea8a5650 with :1.116 activated
Feb  8 18:43:53 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Unknown command complete for opcode 37
Feb  8 18:43:53 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Unknown command complete for opcode 37
Feb  8 18:44:29 laptop bluetoothd[10747]: Stopping
```

Pairing the devices using `bluetooth-agent` and a fixed pin, works hoever there seems to be a problem with pulseaudio now:

```
Feb  8 19:44:29 laptop pulseaudio[2035]: [pulseaudio] module-bluetooth-device.c: Default profile not connected, selecting off profile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue due to lack of an agent running. This has fixed it [Ubuntu 14.04 Bluetooth Magic Mouse doesn't pair (No agent available)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453655/ubuntu-14-04-bluetooth-magic-mouse-doesnt-pair-no-agent-available/453656#453656)